# Given SELECT statement , I want result RECIPE_ID by multiple subquery ?

Tags: php, mysql

I have `ingredient`.`ingredientId` is 709,710,711 this id i am put in ingredient Sub-Query and `AS match_percentage` i am wright `(3*100 / count` is counting of `ingredient`.`ingredientId` , that all comes from my PHP code here i am giving this example for my solution.

Now result like those `RECIPE_ID` that i am pass three `ingredient`.`ingredientId` are match with this table `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` and keep `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`

I want `RECIPE_ID` | 1 and 3 on result . ONLY WHO has that three ids 709,710,711 not even that two 709,710.

Here is my `RECIPE_ID` query:

```
SELECT 
    `recipe`.`recipeId` AS recipe_id ,
    (select count(`recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId) from `recipe_ingredient` where `recipe`.recipeId = `recipe_ingredient`.recipeId) as ingredientCount ,  
    IF(
        (select (3*100 / count(DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId)) from `recipe_ingredient` where `recipe_ingredient`.recipeId = `recipe`.recipeId)>99                      
        ,100
        ,round( (select (3*100 / count(DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId)) from `recipe_ingredient` where `recipe_ingredient`.recipeId = `recipe`.recipeId) ) 
    ) 
    as match_percentage , 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId 
        ORDER BY `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId ASC 
           ) as recipeIngredients 
from `recipe` 
left join `recipe_ingredient` on `recipe_ingredient`.recipeId = `recipe`.recipeId
left join `ingredient` on `ingredient`.ingredientId = `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId   
where  `recipe`.`recipeId` IN( 
                SELECT 
                `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`
                FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
                WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
                IN(
                  SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS linkIng 
                  FROM `ingredient` 
                  WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(709,710,711) or `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(709,710,711)
                )
                GROUP BY `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` 
                ORDER BY `recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId` ASC
              )  

and (select (3*100 / count(DISTINCT `recipe_ingredient`.ingredientId)) from `recipe_ingredient` where `recipe_ingredient`.recipeId = `recipe`.recipeId) > 24  
group by `recipe`.recipeId
```

My Query Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4983/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? Please Check it with other scenario.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4983/8

Comment: i want result like RECIPEID 6,7,10 column has RECIPEFILTERS in 1,5 both values please help me

Comment: Did you find any solution?? This is the wrong way to store values

Comment: You should have one table that has one to many relationship and one entrty for each RECIPEFILTERS. Or the worst case is you can do is do as it is just add ' for all values like '1','5','6'.

Comment: You mean you said i am use LIKE '1','5' function use in mysql ?

Comment: please tell me any other way dear

Comment: Sorry I am not getting.. Try to implement first approach.